# When i try to install the Apache service i get the following errors(Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache

This was the output of `httpd.exe` when I used it to install the service:

```
c:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k install
Installing the 'Apache2.4' service
The 'Apache2.4' service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified do
main name, using fe80::e15e:d9f5:2f45:c0d1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globa
lly to suppress this message
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a service listening on port 80, or you have overlapping Listen directives in your Apache configuration.  For the former, check netstat -bano output.